# Use selected text instead of selectedIndex

Tags: c#, combobox, win32gui

I have a `dataset` connected to a `bindinglist` that is connected to a `combobox` in win32.

I would like to make "Computer" to be selected as a `displaymember` in the `combobox` when I have a private string with value "Computer".

The main issue is that it doesn't work to use `SelectedText` in the `combobox` to make "Computer" to be selected but it works properly when I use `selectedIndex`. But, in order to use `selectedIndex`, you have to know the row number from table in order to make the text to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Not sure because of tags, I am assuming you are using WinForms for your application).*

Try the following:

```
combobox.SelectedValue = "Computer";
```